# CSS z-index (stacking context)

Tags: html, css, z-index

I wanted to know if what I want to do is even possible, since I couldn't get it to work:

```
<body>
    <header>
        <panel>
            <login>
            </login>
        </panel>
    </header>
    
    <content>
    </content>
</body>
```

Here's the hierarchy I want:

1. `<panel>` **above** `<header>`
2. `<login>` **under both** `<header>` **and** `<panel>`
3. `<login>` **above** `<content>`

**Additional Info:**

`<login>` is a `position: absolute` login form which slides down from beneath the `<header>` on demand but should remain above the page's `<content>`

Hope you could help me out..

Comment: What have you tried? At this point, ideally you should at least have a base style to work on.

Comment: If login doesn't have to be a child of header and panel than this may be possible. For a good explanation of stacking order, see [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Understanding_CSS_z-index/The_stacking_context)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regrettably, child nodes cannot have a `z-index` lower than their ancestors. To get the effect you want, you would have to move `login` outside of `header`.

## Example

```
<header>
 <div class="panel"><!-- Panel Here --></div>
</header>
<div class="login"><!-- Log In Here --></div>
<div class="content"><!-- Content Here --></div>
```

***Note:** I've changed your markup slightly to conform to HTML standards. If you wish to continue using the invalid markup, simply replace `<div class="XXX">` with `<XXX>` and corresponding `</div>` with `<XXX>` where `XXX` is the value of the `class` attribute.*

Comment: @tamir, thought that might be the case, but you never know :P Glad I could help!